# Mongodb Retrieve records based on only day and month

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-data-mongodb

I am new in writing aggregate queries in Mongo DB + Spring

**Scenario:** We are storing birthDate(Jjava.uti.Date) in mongo db which got stored as ISO date. Now we are trying to look for the records which are matching with the dayOfMonth and Month only. So that we can corresponding object from the list.

I had gone through few solutions and here is the way I am trying but this is giving me a null set of records.

```
Aggregation agg = Aggregation.newAggregation(
Aggregation.project().andExpression("dayOfMonth(birthDate)").as("day").andExpression("month(birthDate)")
                        .as("month"),
                Aggregation.group("day", "month"));
        AggregationResults<Employee> groupResults = mongoTemplate.aggregate(agg, Employee.class, Employee.class);
```

I also tried applying a a query with the help of Criteria but this is also giving me a Employee object which all null content.

```
Aggregation agg = Aggregation.newAggregation(Aggregation.match(Criteria.where("birthDate").lte(new Date())),    Aggregation.project().andExpression("dayOfMonth(birthDate)").as("day").andExpression("month(birthDate)")
                            .as("month"),
                    Aggregation.group("day", "month"));
            AggregationResults<Employee> groupResults = mongoTemplate.aggregate(agg, Employee.class, Employee.class);
```

I must missing some important thing which is giving me these null data.

**Additional Info**: Employee object has only birthDate(Date) and email(String) in it

Answer (score 0):

Please try to specify the fields to be included in the `$project` stage.

```
project("birthDate", "...").andExpression("...
```

> The _id field is, by default, included in the output documents. To include any other fields from the input documents in the output documents, you must explicitly specify the inclusion in $project.
>   see: *[MongoDBReference - $project (aggregation)](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/project/#include-existing-fields)*

I've created [DATAMONGO-2200](https://jira.spring.io/browse/DATAMONGO-2200) to add an option to project directly onto the fields of a given domain type via something like `project(Employee.class)`.